# Checking to see what elements in 2 arraylists are the same

Tags: arraylist

I'm working on some code to build a wingbox from some the geometry of a wing.  I have an integer arraylist (node) of all the nodes on the wing, and I have an integer arralist (ohnode) of the nodes that I want to trim in order to make my wingbox. How can I compare the 2 arraylists and delete the elements in the node arraylist so that all I'm left with are the nodes that weren't in the ohnode arraylist?

I haven't found many good examples comparing arraylists, most of them were for arrays.  Would code for arrays work for arraylists, like arrays.equal?

Basically, I want to run through through all the nodes on the node arraylist, and if

Answer (score 0):

Display common elements from two arraylists

```
ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList();
 a1.add("a");
 a1.add("b");
 a1.add("c");

a2.add("a");
a2.add("b");
a2.add("c"); 
a2.add("d");
a2.add("e");
    int array1Size = a1.size();
    int array2Size = a2.size();
    if (a1.size() > a2.size()) {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a2.size(); i++)            {
            if (((String)a1.get(i)).equals((String)a2.get(i)))  {
                System.out.println((String)a2.get(i));
            }
            k = i;
        }
       }
    else {
       int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
            if (((String)a1.get(i)).equals((String)a2.get(i))) {
                System.out.println((String)a1.get(i));
            }
            k = i;
        }
     }
```

then loop through all common elements in 2nd arraylist, and delete it.